# How to use authentication with chrome.proxy api

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to add authentication so that only my chrome extension can connect to my http web proxy (squid).However i haven't find anything regarding authentication in the [chrome.proxy docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/proxy)

Answer (score 1):

You can add authentication by calling  ['*chrome.webRequest - onAuthRequired*'](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) API. You must declare the '*webRequest*' permission in the extension manifest to use the web request API. '*onAuthRequired*' fires when a request requires authentication of the user.